# I M Isaacs Algebra Exercise 9.4

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I am a PhD student in the represention theory of finite groups. One of my friends and I solved all exercises in the book [I M Isaacs - Algebra A Graduate Course](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/100) except for the following exercise in Chapter 9(transfer theory):

**(Exercise 9.4)**

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P\in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $N={\rm N}_G(P)$. Suppose $z\in {\rm Z}(N)\cap P$ and $z\notin P'$. Show that $z\notin G'$.

HINT: Use the Transfer evaluation lemma. Note that if $tz^nt^{-1}\in P$, then $tz^nt^{-1}=z^n$ by Lemma 9.12.

It is equivalent to the following proposition:

**Proposition**

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P\in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$, then $ {\rm Z}({\rm N}_G(P))\cap P\cap G'\le P'$.

**Lemma 9.12 (Burnside)**

Let $P\in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and suppose that $x,y\in {\rm C}_G(P)$ are conjugate in G. Then $x$ and $y$ are conjugate in ${\rm N}_G(P)$.

In this problem, it is hard to show that if $tz^nt^{-1}\in P$, then $tz^nt^{-1}=z^n$.

I asked a professor in our university, he can't solve it as well.

Here is my idea about this question:

By contradiction, suppose that $z\in G'$, then $z\in {\rm Z}(N)\cap P\cap G'$. In order to use Lemma 9.12，We can choose two elements $tz^nt^{-1}$ and $z^n$，So it suffices to show that $tz^nt^{-1}\in{\rm C}_G(P)$. But I don't know whether it is true or not. Maybe some results about fusion and focal subgroups are useful.

I checked this question for some classes of finite groups. I guess that it is not true for simple groups.

Could you give us some help? Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess this was closed because it is an exercise in a book, but questions on group theory that are much easier than this have been asked on MO recently without being closed. I have not been able to solve this problem myself, although I don't have access to this particular textbook.

Comment: I think the exercise is wrong, here is a question about it on Math SE: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577477/fusion-in-the-normaliser-of-a-sylow-subgroup/4577828#4577828) (There was also an earlier question here, but it seems to have been deleted)

Comment: @spin I suggest that you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt the book can be found for free on libgen.

Comment: @Nemo Downloading books that I don't own already gives me a guilty conscience! (That's not to say that I have never done it, but I didn't have enough motivation in this case.)

Comment: I remember getting stuck on this problem many years ago: http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-algebraist/2010/0658.htm#0658.0001

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the exercise is incorrect (and so is the hint).

There was a question before about this same exercise at math.stackexchange; the answer there gives a counterexample. Link: [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577477/fusion-in-the-normaliser-of-a-sylow-subgroup/).

Comment: I spend a lot of time on it. Thank you very much!